# Problems rendering a round button with java.swing. Why isn't this code working?

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing a Java application that demands a customized button. I'm using Swing for the GUI and found myself limited to some tricky solutions.
Here's one I found (from [this website](https://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/07/create-round-image-jbutton.html)). It's supposed to use a custom image for the button and make it round.

```
public class RoundButton extends JButton
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected Shape shape, base;

    public RoundButton() 
    {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public RoundButton(Icon icon) 
    {
        this(null, icon);
    }

    public RoundButton(String text) 
    {
        this(text, null);
    }

    public RoundButton(Action a) 
    {
        this();
        setAction(a);
    }

    public RoundButton(String text, Icon icon) 
    {
        setModel(new DefaultButtonModel());
        init(text, icon);

        if(icon==null) return;

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1,1,1,1));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setFocusPainted(false);
        //setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        init_shape();
      }

      protected void init_shape() 
      {
          if(!getBounds().equals(base)) 
          {
              Dimension s = getPreferredSize();
              base = getBounds();
              shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, s.width-1, s.height-1);
          }
      }

      @Override 
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
      {
        Icon icon = getIcon();
        Insets i = getInsets();
        int iw = Math.max(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
        return new Dimension(iw+i.right+i.left, iw+i.top+i.bottom);
      }

      @Override 
      protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) 
      {
          init_shape();
          Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
          g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                  RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
          g2.setColor(getBackground());
          //g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
          g2.draw(shape);
          g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                  RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
      }

      @Override 
      public boolean contains(int x, int y) 
      {
        init_shape();
        return shape.contains(x, y);
        //or return super.contains(x, y) && ((image.getRGB(x, y) >> 24) & 0xff) > 0;
      }
}
```

Here's some test code I wrote:

```
public class BtnTest extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private RoundButton btn;

    public BtnTest()
    {
        init_components();
    }

    private void init_components()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setResizable(false);

        btn = new RoundButton(
                new ImageIcon("/path/to/file.png"));
        btn.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                System.out.println("click");
            }
        });

        add(btn);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BtnTest frame = new BtnTest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

The problem is: the image's rendered away from the button location, so my ActionListener isn't triggered when I press the icon, but when the region inside the black circle (top left) is clicked. Can someone explain me why, and offer a solution?

PS: I'm in my first year of Java programming, so make it as simple as possible please.

PS2: JavaFX and other external solutions are out of question, this must be done pure Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is: the image's rendered away from the button location,

What is happening is that you are adding the button to the frame without using a constraint. By default this means the component is added to `BorderLayout.CENTER`, which means the component will be sized to fill the entire frame.

Also, by default, when you paint an `Icon` in a `JLabel`, the `Icon` is centered in the spaced available to the label, so you see the `Icon` in the center of the frame. Try resizing the frame to see the Icon move.

However, you hard code the painting of the `Border` to be painted at the (0, 0) location of the label so it paints at the top/left.

The `contains()` method is also defined from the top/left of the component, so mouse detection only works from the top/left, not the center.

This means your button must always be painted at its "preferred size" in order for it to be painted properly and for the `contains(...)` method to work.

A simple way to demonstrate this is to use:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
```

The `FlowLayout` does respect the preferred size of the button, so the `Icon` and `Border` will be painted properly.

Other options (instead of changing the layout of the frame) are to use a "wrapper" panel for the button. For example:

```
//add(btn);
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel(); // default to FlowLayout
wrapper.add( btn );
add( wrapper );
```

Now when you add the panel to the frame, the panel will grow in size, but the button will still be painted at its preferred size.

```
btn.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
```

Also, not you should NOT be using this method. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size/location of the component. The above statement is effectively ignored.